# Is organizing "piggybacked" referendums something unusual in EU?

Tags: election, european-union, referendum

Romanians were also called to vote for a referendum when voting for EU Parliament elections in 2019. However, the [organizing for diaspora voting was very problematic](https://www.romaniajournal.ro/politics/fm-melescanu-refuses-to-assume-responsibility-over-romanians-failing-to-vote-in-diaspora/) and many could not vote at all:

> An impressive number of Romanians living and working abroad have come
>   to polls on Sunday to vote at the European elections and at the
>   referendum for justice. Unfortunately, the polling stations were
>   insufficient, and problems were also encountered on the scarce voting
>   stamps, ballot papers or boxes, so that a considerable amount of
>   people did not manage to cast their votes.

I cannot find a source now, but the Foreign Ministry also blamed the referendum for putting extra pressure on the voting polls.

From my perspective "piggyback" (organizing in the same time) a referendum sounds like a great idea since it reduces the costs and also might motivate the voters (they come if they wish to vote for at least one of the elections). However, I am wondering if this practice is heavily used across EU or it rarely happens so.

**Question:** Is organizing "piggybacked" referendums something unusual in EU? By EU I mean any European Union country.

Comment: If I understand correctly the Foreign Ministry are saying "everyone who's allowed to vote turning up to vote is a problem". Is that about right? That could really use a source, I hope you do find it.

Comment: https://www.euractiv.com/section/eu-elections-2019/news/debate-in-france-over-holding-referendum-on-same-day-as-european-election/

Comment: @Jontia - yes, he said that, but I clearly remember that he blamed the referendum - [source](https://www.digifm.ro/stiri/t-melescanu-da-vina-pentru-haosul-din-26-mai-pe-estimari-gresite-si-pe-intrebarile-referendumului-40375) (Romanian).

Comment: by "in EU" do in any election of a country that is part of the EU, or just in elections to the European Parliament?

Comment: @katatahito - I mean any elections of a country within EU. I will change to clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR: No, it's not unusual.

After going going through related wiki pages, I found following instances of referenda being held on same day as any elections.

For purpose of the list ECC (direct predecessor of EU, established in 1957) counts as EU.

While ECC was founded in 1957, first elections to European parliament were held on 1979. This however changes nothing, since question asks about any elections concurrent with referendum, not just European elections.

If bullet point listing example contains more than one link it means that wiki article about referendum referendum concurrent with election does NOT mention this fact, second link is election(s) concurrent with referendum

1. Austria: 0, 1 referendum since joining EU
2. Belgium: 0, 0 referenda since joining EU
3. Bulgaria: 2, 2 referenda since joining EU

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Bulgarian_electoral_code_referendum
   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Bulgarian_referendum
4. Croatia: 0, 1 referendum since joining EU
5. Cyprus: 0, 0 referenda since joining EU
6. Czech Republic: 0, 0 referenda since joining EU
7. Denmark: 3, 9 referenda since joining EU

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Danish_Act_of_Succession_referendum
   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Danish_Unified_Patent_Court_membership_referendum
   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Danish_European_Union_opt-out_referendum
8. Estonia: 0, 0 referenda since joining EU
9. Finland: 0, 0 referenda since joining EU
10. France: 0, 10 referenda since joining EU
11. Germany: 0, 0 referenda since joining EU
12. Greece: 0, 1 referendum since joining EU
13. Hungary: 0, 3 referenda since joining EU
14. Ireland: 8, 26 referenda since joining EU

    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninth_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland
    - articles do not cross link

      1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/November_1992_Irish_constitutional_referendums
      2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_Irish_general_election
    - articles do not cross link

      1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeenth_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland
      2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_Irish_presidential_election
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland
    - articles do not cross link

      1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-seventh_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland
      2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Irish_local_elections
      3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_European_Parliament_election_in_Ireland
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Irish_constitutional_referendums
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-seventh_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland
    - articles do not cross link

      1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-eighth_Amendment_of_the_Constitution_of_Ireland
      2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Irish_local_elections
      3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_European_Parliament_election_in_Ireland
15. Italy: 1 (6 unverifiable but highly unlikely), 21 referenda since joining EU

    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_Italian_advisory_referendum
    - can not verify 1997, page for local elections in 1997 does not exist
    - can not verify 2000, page for local elections in 2000 does not exist, regional elections of 2000 were NOT on same day
    - can not verify 2001, page for local elections in 2001 does not exist, regional and general elections of 2001 were NOT on same day
    - can not verify 2003, page for local elections in 2003 does not exist, regional elections of 2003 were NOT on same day
    - can not verify 2005, page for local elections in 2005 does not exist, regional elections of 2005 were NOT on same day
    - can not verify 2009, page for local elections in 2009 does not exist, regional and european elections of 2009 were NOT on same day
16. Latvia: 0, 5 referenda since joining EU
17. Lithuania: 3, 4 referenda since joining EU

    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Lithuanian_nuclear_power_referendum
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Lithuanian_nuclear_power_referendum
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Lithuanian_constitutional_referendum
18. Luxembourg: 0, 2 referenda since joining EU
19. Malta: 1, 2 referenda since joining EU

    - articles do not cross link

      1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Maltese_spring_hunting_referendum
      2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Maltese_local_elections
20. Netherlands: 1, 2 referenda since joining EU

    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Dutch_Intelligence_and_Security_Services_Act_referendum
21. Poland: 0, 1 referendum since joining EU
22. Portugal: 0, 3 referenda since joining EU
23. Romania: 3, 6 referenda since joining EU

    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Romanian_electoral_system_referendum
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Romanian_parliamentary_reform_referendum
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Romanian_referendum
24. Slovakia: 0 (1 unverifiable but unlikely), 2 referenda since joining EU

    - referendum of 2010 unverifiable, page for local elections of 2010 does not exist, parliamentary elections of 2010 were NOT on same day
25. Slovenia: 1 (2 unverifiable but highly unlikely), 12 referenda since joining EU

    - articles do not cross link

      1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Slovenian_privatisation_referendum
      2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Slovenian_presidential_election
    - can not verify 2 of 2010 referenda, because page for local elections of 2010 does not exist
    - can not verify referendum of 2014, because page about local elections does not exist, parliamentary and European elections were NOT on same day
26. Spain: 0, 2 referenda since joining EU
27. Sweden: 0, 1 referendum since joining EU
28. United Kingdom: 1, 3 referenda since joining EU

    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_United_Kingdom_Alternative_Vote_referendum

**Summary:
I counted 24 referenda happening at the same day as other elections out of total of 120 referenda happening in EU member states until this day. There isn't much of a pattern that I can see. It appears to be dependant on country's tradition (compare France to Denmark and Ireland to Italy) than anything.**

Comment: Not unusual, but not common either. A description that could be applied to referendums in general.

Comment: @Jontia Compared to random chance of having election and referendum on same day, I'd hazard a guess that it's rather common.